# Extracting nested zip archives with Ant

Tags: ant, unzip

I need to process a zip archive which itself contains zip archives which all follow the same structure:

```
main.zip/
  foo-1.txt
  foo-1.zip/
    ... 
    tests/
    ...
  bar-1.txt
  bar-1.zip/
    ... 
    tests/
    ...
  bar-2.txt
  bar-2.zip/
    ... 
    tests/
    ...
  foobar-1.txt
  foobar-1.zip/
    ... 
    tests/
    ...
```

I want to extract the `txt` files and the `tests` directories into a structure like this:

```
 foo/
   1/
     submission.txt
     tests/
 bar/
   1/
     submission.txt
     tests/
   2/
     submission.txt
     tests/
 foobar/
   1/
     submission.txt
     tests/
```

I managed to get the directory structure and the text files into the right place:

```
<target name="extract submissions">
  <copy todir="${basedir}">
    <zipfileset refid="submissions.zip"/>
<mapper type="regexp" from="(.*)-(.*)\.txt" to="\1/\2/\submission.txt"/>
  </copy>
</target>
```

But now I am stuck how to access the tests directory inside the inner zips. I tried an intermediate step where I copied the inner zips into the place where the tests directories should end up. But how can I access the content of a zip archive without knowing its exact path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a pure Ant solution:

```
<target name="extract submissions">
  <copy todir="${basedir}">
    <zipfileset refid="submissions.zip"/>
    <mapper type="regexp" from="(.*)-(.*)\.txt" to="\1/\2/\submission.txt"/>
  </copy>

  <subant genericantfile="${basedir}/build.xml" target="extract submission">
    <dirset dir="${basedir}" includes="*/*"/>
  </subant>
 </target>

<target name="extract submission">
  <copy todir="tests">
    <zipfileset refid="submission.zip"/>
    <mapper type="regexp" from="tests/(.*)" to="\1"/>
  </copy>
</target>
```

The first target extracts the outer zip file and calls the second target on each extracted directory. This is achieved by a subant. The second target then unzips an inner zip file. Since it is applied in any subdirectory, all the inner zips are extracted.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a place where standard ant tasks are not sufficient. So you reach for custom tasks or a script workaround. Javascript fits best as it requires no additional dependencies, jdk6 is enough. And usually only java programming knowledge is needed. Plus ant api, which must be downloaded with [ant manual](http://ant.apache.org/manualdownload.cgi).

The following example finds all zips in current directory and extract each zip into `tests` directory created in the zip file directory.

```
  <target name="un2">
    <fileset dir="." includes="**/*.zip" id="zipset" />
    <script language="javascript">
      it = project.getReference("zipset").iterator();
      while (it.hasNext()) {
        zipFile = new java.io.File(it.next());
        java.lang.System.out.println(zipFile.getParent());
        unzipTask = project.createTask("unzip");
        unzipTask.setSrc(zipFile);
        dest = new java.io.File(zipFile.getParent(), "tests")
        unzipTask.setDest(dest);
        unzipTask.execute();
      }
    </script>
  </target>
```